# AppCenter in UWP with sqlite-pcl-net

Tags: uwp, sqlite-net, visual-studio-app-center

I'm using AppCenter and SQLite in my multi-platform application (Xamarin Forms for Android and iOS, and native UWP (not Xamarin)). I also use SQLite.

It worked fine, but now I updated to newer versions for both AppCenter and SQLite, and I got an exception on AppCenter.Start call. Exception is "Method not found: 'Void SQLite.SQLiteAsyncConnection..ctor(System.String, Boolean)'."

AppCenter version - 1.9.0
SQLite-net-pcl - 1.5.231

Any ideas how to fix it? I don't want to downgrade SQLite-net-pcl, as I actually was on beta before to make it work with UWP and Xamarin.

Comment: I checked the Nuget Installation on github. You might need to note the **Important**: You will need to add the nuget package to both your PCL project and your platform-dependent project.

Comment: I have that added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it's known issue https://github.com/Microsoft/AppCenter-SDK-DotNet/issues/753, need to wait for fix.